# How to get content of an element in the html returned by jquery post

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery post request which return a tabular data in html format
This is the jQuery post

```
    jQuery('#chem_search').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var itemcode=jQuery('[name="itemcode"]').val();
                jQuery.post("chemical_search_query.php", {"itemcode":itemcode},    function(data) {
        jQuery('#type2').html(data);
        });
    });
```

the data returned by the ajax request is like this

```
    echo "<div id='dar'><table class='s_report'><tr><th>Item Code</th><th>Description</th><th>Unit</th><th>Op. Stock</th><th>Recd. Qty</th><th>Total Receipts</th><th>Used Qty</th><th>Available Stock</th></tr>";
  $sr_no=0;
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

                {


                    $dateform=explode('-',$row['recd_date']);

                    $dateform2=explode('-',$row['analysed_date']);
                    $dateform3=explode('-',$row['report_send']);

                    echo "<td><div id='itemcode'>" . $row['item_code']. "</div></td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['uom'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['open_stock'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['recd_total'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $sum=$row['open_stock']+$row['recd_total'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td><div id='iss'>" . $row['issue_qty'] . "</div></td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $available=$sum-$row['issue_qty'] . "</td>";

                    echo "</tr>";
                }

                echo "</table></div>";}
```

I want to get content of the div "itemcode" when I click on the div "iss". I know how to get content of the div which is clicked. But that is not the requirement. Any option?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$('#type2').on('click', '#iss', function(e){
    var ic = $(this).closest('td').closest('tr').find('td > div#itemcode').text();
});
```

Also, I see `echo "</tr>";` at the end but didn't see the opening `<tr>` tag, so make sure you nest tags properly, otherwise, it  won't work.

Comment: This is not working "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: If I use this <br/> jQuery(document).delegate("#iss","click",function(e){
  
 
 var itemcode= jQuery(this).text();
 
 alert(itemcode);});<br/> It will show the content of the div iss.

Comment: This will not work because the id itemcode is not known since it is dynamically loaded by the jQuery and not initially

Comment: I mixed part of my code with part of your answer anad this is working : jQuery(document).delegate("#iss","click",function(e){ var ic = jQuery(this).closest('td').closest('tr').find('td > div#itemcode').text(); alert(ic); });   please modify your answer and I will give an up votew

Comment: @mansoondreamz, This will work, because of delegated event handler using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). [Check this working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/vDRNH/)

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use class instead of id because id cannot be duplicate. so use itemcode and iss both as class. Also missing opening tr for each item block.

var item = $(this).parent().parent().find('.itemcode').text();
var item = $(this).parent().parent().find('.itemcode').html();